# Dropdown selection to populate a cell in multiple sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, dropdown, show-hide, setvalue

I have a dropdown on sheet1 (overview) that I need to hide rows in the same sheet and populate a cell in multiple other sheets (sheet) when a certain selection is made

if dropdown = ACHIEVED then hide 2 rows in sheet1 and populate cell A1 with value of "5"

This is what I have but it doesn't seem to be working although the script runs with no errors

```
var overview = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Overview');
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


["T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6"].forEach(function (s) {
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(s);

var dropdownValueEnglish = overview.getRange("E80:F80").getValue();
var targetRangeEnglish = sheet.getRange("B69:F69");

var dropdownValueEnglish = overview.getRange("E80:F80").getValue();
var targetRangeEnglish = sheet.getRange("B69:F69");
if (dropdownValueEnglish == "ACHIEVED") {
  overview.hideRows(81, 2);
  sheet.getRange("F71").setValue("5");
}
else {
  overview.showRows(81, 2);
  sheet.getRange("F71").setValue("");
}
```

I wondered if it is because my dropdown is in 2 merged cells but I have tried to copy the value to a single cell first and it still doesn't work. Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Are you able to share dummy data for the community to replicate? It does not have to be exactly your data if it contains sensitive information. This is just so we can visualize and replicate what you have as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

If wish to get the values in "E80:F80" the you would have to use getValues() and it returns a 2d array.  This should work by just using  E80 if that it not what you wish they please provide a bit more explanation.

```
function dropdownSelectionToPopulateacell() {
  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77322218/dropdown-selection-to-populate-a-cell-in-multiple-sheets
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  ["T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6"].forEach(s => {
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName(s);
    var dve = osh.getRange("E80").getValue();
    if (dve == "ACHIEVED") {
      osh.hideRows(81, 2);
      sh.getRange("F71").setValue("5");
    }
    else {
      osh.showRows(81, 2);
      sh.getRange("F71").setValue("");
    }
  });
}
```

- [Range.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)